# How to explain to a ~$12-16$ year-old student who is weak at maths, that $\ 38 \times 27 \times 14 = 27 \times 14 \times 38$?

Tags: secondary-education, multiplication

How to explain to a ~$12-16$ year-old student who is weak at maths, that $\ 38 \times 27 \times 14 = 27 \times 14 \times 38,\ $ and that $\ 3.4 \times 10^{-6} \times 2.1 \times 10^{-5} = 3.4\times 2.1 \times 10^{-6} \times 10^{-5},\ $ and that $\ 11^4 \times 7^7 \times 3^5 \times 5^2 = 3^5 \times 5^2 \times 7^7 \times 11^4,\ $ and that $\ \frac{ 8 }{ 14 } \times \frac{ 3 }{ 4 } \times \frac{ 7 }{ 11 } \times \frac{ 22 }{ 9 } = \frac{ 8 \times 3 \times 7 \times 22 }{ 14 \times 4 \times 11 \times 9 } = \frac{ 7 \times 8 \times 22 \times 3 }{ 14 \times 4 \times 11 \times 9 } = \frac{ 7 }{ 14 } \times \frac{ 8 }{ 4 } \times \frac{ 22 }{ 11 } \times \frac{ 3 }{ 9 },\ $ and so on.

I have been in this situation a few times, where it was necessary - or at least extremely helpful - for them to use the fact that if the value of the product of finitely many terms remains unchanged if terms being multiplied are rearranged within the product. [Maybe there's a better way of wording this, but anyway...]

I proceeded to explain that, "you can swap any two numbers without affecting the result due to $ab = ba,$ and therefore we can always re-arrange the numbers in the original product $\ 38 \times 27 \times 14\ $ in any order we want, without affecting the value of the product." However, upon reflection, I think this line of reasoning is too complicated for students who are weak at maths to understand. This is for two reasons. First, they have to understand that swapping any two numbers gives the same result, which is not necessarily obvious, and secondly, they have to understand that there is a way to keep swapping terms to get from the first product $\ (\ 38 \times 27 \times 14 \ )\ $ to the second product $\ (\ 27 \times 14 \times 38\ )\ $, which also is not necessarily obvious.

Although, when I was that age, I found both of those steps "obvious", even if I did not know the mathematical language to prove it formally.

And introducing rigor is not advisable for weak students either.

So is there a completely different (perhaps visual?) way to explain this phenomenon/fact that is easy for a weak student to understand, that can also be extended to the product of four, or more numbers? Or can it be explained along the lines I am trying to, but in a way that is easier to understand?

Or is this just one of those "facts" that you tell students of that age that they "just have to accept"?

Comment: "So is there a completely different (perhaps visual?) way to explain this phenomenon/fact that is easy for a weak student to understand". It would be helpful to know what this student's visual concept of multiplication is to start with. Based on your comment to an answer below, some of these students don't know how to find the area of a rectangle. So, what should we assume they can do with multiplication?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that care should be exercised with the words used. Saying that we can always rearrange the numbers in the original product could lead some to posit that $38\times 27 = 32 \times 87$. I would want to say "we can rearrange the *factors* in the original product" to be careful.

Comment: @NickC "what should we assume they can do with multiplication?" That they have learned their $10$ x $10$ times tables reasonably well and they can also multiply two two-digit numbers together with good success, although they might struggle multiplying two three-digit numbers or more, although this varies greatly from student to student (I am referring to "weaker" students here only).

Comment: Every time I see this question I get confused about what is really happening here. We have a young person who is already being perceived as weak at mathematics, being taught by someone who is categorizing an axiom as obvious or not obvious. Then there is the part where repeated uses of two different axioms is also categorized as obvious or not obvious. I think the students' confusion is completely reasonable and not thinking it is anything else is entirely the first step. If motivating axioms and their applications is the question, I wish this question were re-worded.

Comment: @cheyne Firstly, "Rearranging the order of finitely many terms when multiplying doesn't change the result", which is what is being discussed here, is not an axiom. Commutativity of multiplication, that is $ab=ba$, is one of the axioms of multiplication, sure, but that is not *only* what is being discussed here. Secondly, with weaker students, referring to axioms is ill-advised, so I think we should steer clear of that, especially in algebra, which weaker students tend to find unrelatable and difficult as it is. So no, I don't think we should involving axioms helps resolve this issue.

Comment: However, what I do agree with you on is that my question should clarify some specific things, which I will try to do tonight.

Comment: hi @AdamRubinson I know that is not an axiom, that's why I wrote "repeated uses of two different axioms" when referring to that. I don't understand where your assumptions about "weak students" and "avoiding axioms" are coming from? There is literally no other way to be honest about what is happening other than it's "a rule we agree on". If you are looking for advice on *motivating* an axiom, then the only thing constructive I could think of that others haven't said is talking about how many outfits you can construct depending on n-number of shirts, m-pants, l-socks, etc. Happy to say more.

Comment: Maybe I am conflating "formal proof", which below-average students aren't ready for, with proof outlines i.e. *explanations*, which is what these students need.

Comment: I do hope you will elaborate on the question as you suggested you might do. One thing I'm curious about is how the issue arose in the first place. In your particular example one way to proceed would be to observe that (1) $38\times27\times14=38\times378$, (2) $27\times14\times38=378\times38$, and (3) $38\times378=378\times38$.  I'm wondering which of these steps would be most problematic for these students. You say that the property that swapping any two factors gives the same result is nonobvious to them, but would that apply to (3), or only when the two factors are embedded in a larger ...

Comment: ... product? My guess is the latter, but I'm wondering whether you agree. And if the embedding in a larger product is the problem, then the issue might simply be that they have difficulty imagining that any manipulation of $12\times23\times17$ apart from evaluating it would be useful or meaningful. So $12\times23\times17=12\times17\times23$ may leave them, not so much in doubt, as just plain mystified. (Why would someone do *that??*) Assuming (3) is ok for them--and (2) seems likely ok also since it corresponds to the left-to-right evaluation procedure most students ...

Comment: find natural--the only difficulty, if any, must be (1). But then again maybe this example isn't so representative of the ones that give students problems. If (1) *is* problematic, it may be that they don't have a good grasp of associativity.

Comment: Your recent edits to the question lead me to ask how you confirmed that commutativity of multiple factors was the sticking point for your students. The three examples you added all bring in extra issues--scientific notation, exponentiation, fractions--any of which might be the actual source of confusion. Only the original example is about commutativity of multiple factors in its pure form.

Comment: @WillOrrick You are right that I should check for multiple possible points of confusion. I already do this to the best of my ability of course, but maybe I can improve on doing this? Anyway, for the sake of this question, assume that I already checked that the student did not have those extra issues. "How" I did this was by testing the student on those potential issues first, with multiple-choice questions and furthermore asking them to do some problem questions.

Comment: I guess what I'm imagining is a student who who can  handle two concepts in isolation, but then has trouble when they are combined. It's actually good when a student who understands commutativity for products of natural numbers entertains doubts when it is applied to rational numbers. Extending the domain of applicability of a concept requires proof. Besides that, all kinds of other issues come into play: do they know that $10^{-6}$ is a rational number? Do they know the precedence rules and so are aware that the exponent $-6$ attaches only to the $10$ and not the surrounding factors? etc.

Comment: The smoking gun would be if they were tested on commutativity in the most elementary setting and failed to apply it correctly. E.g. without a calculator, tell me which is is the greater number (or whether the two numbers are equal). $273\times 67$ or $71\times 273$? $10\times7\times 621$ or $621\times73$? $17\times11\times13$ or $17\times13\times11$?

Comment: Now that I think about it: what is "weak at math"? I mean, if you show him (or her) "1 + 2 x 3", does (s)he realise that your are adding something to the result of a multiplication or does (s)he only realise that the two crosses are different, one being straight "+" and the other being rotated "x"?

Comment: @Dominique Most students I have tutored are not awful at arithmetic in general, although all students make mistakes with arithmetic: I associate "weaker students" (at arithmetic) as the ones who make mistakes more often than "strong students". But I don't think I have encountered a student who has *absolutely no* conception or understanding of addition or multiplication when it comes to, for example, (real life) word problems, for example a money calculation problem. Even the weakest student I have tutored had an inkling for when to add and when to multiply. Does this address your question?

Answer (score 8):

For up to three dimensions you could use the concept of "area of a rectangle" or "volume of a rectangular cuboid". Use only numbers (no variables) and let the student pick a convention like "the first factor is the width and the second factor is the height (and the third one the depth)". Then use lots of examples and let the student draw many rectangles (or, if material is available and the task doesn't seem silly, arrange dice or something else in rectangular patterns) and have him or her realise ("accept?") that ab = ba always, because there are the same number of unit squares in both rectangles. Extend to three dimensions and then generalise for arbitrary numbers of factors.

I think this is about "looking at enough examples to accept the commutative law".

Comment: This may work for some weak students. But many weak students don't know how to work out the area of a rectangle, so considerable time would have to be spent working on this in order for your method to be plausible. Also, you haven't said how you get *from* the student knowing that "the commutative law works" *to* "you can rearrange the numbers in any order and the product is the same".

Comment: If these students cannot work out the area of a rectangle, what is their mental model of multiplication?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm not sure if even I have *one* "mental model of multiplication". Personally, I have *many*, and I pick and choose the one I need for the problem at hand. As for the mental model of multiplication these kids have who are not good at calculating areas, I think their mental model might be something like "four times five is like when you have five lots of four coins". That seems more likely (to me) than them defaulting to area as their mental model. And whilst this model can be linked to area, I'm not sure that they necessarily do make this link. But maybe I am wrong about that

Comment: @AdamRubinson I don't think that your question is answerable until you can figure out what mental model your students are working with.  If they are thinking of piles of coin, five piles of three each *feels* very different from three piles of five each.  It is not obvious that piles can be rearranged in this way.  So *if* that is their model, I would suggest that step 1 is to show them how to arrange those piles into rectangular arrays of coins, where commutativity is easier to spot.

Comment: @XanderHenderson that's a really good point. The part of my question that isn't being addressed here though, is: let's say the student now understands the commutative law. How do you then show them (i.e. use the commutative law) that "you can rearrange the numbers in any order and the product is the same"? Is the answer, "looking at enough examples to accept the commutative law" [the last line of this answer]?

Comment: *because there are the same number of unit squares in both rectangles* --- Or just note that the area of the rectangle does not change if the rectangle is rotated (in its plane, around its "center") by 90 degrees. Similar for 3-dimensional versions, although probably need a physical model one can turn around in various ways.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro yes, I guess my hang-up is with four or more numbers, as visualising in four dimensions is impossible. And if they infer the same pattern as from two and three numbers *without (induction) proof*, is that a good or a bad thing? I would view it as bad if they have accepted a generalisation without justification, as this mindset is a precursor to making all sorts of mistakes in maths, as there are many things in maths that are true for $n=2$ and $n=3$ but fails for $n=4$ etc...

Comment: @Adam Rubinson: For weak students, which I interpret as those not planning to attend college except perhaps a community college (which might not be until several years after high school graduation), I wouldn't worry about it. And if you do, forget about induction -- focus on pointing out that this is actually something one might need absolute proof of, and focus on what is at stake. For example, without adding any numbers, how can we be absolutely sure that $(325+228)+(132+947)=[(325+228)+132]+947$? Probably have to describe each in words, describing explicitly what one does and in what order.

Comment: In thinking about this some more, and assuming I'm dealing with weak students (who might have great difficulty later in getting past school algebra) but in retrospect this might also be enlightening to stronger students, you could imagine 4 piles of sticks on the ground -- $325$ sticks, $228$ sticks, $132$ sticks,  $947$ sticks. The various ways of adding these 4 numbers (different order, different associative methods) correspond to pushing the piles of sticks together in different ways and in different orders. 
Since sticks don't disappear from existence or come into existence $\dots$

Comment: I just realized we were talking about multiplying 4 numbers, and I switched to adding 4 numbers! However, maybe the stuff with sticks (or use something else for those who didn't spend most of their childhood in rural woods and fields) could be helpful elsewhere in your teaching.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson: By the way, even proving generalized associativity alone (i.e. keep the numbers in the same order, so we're not also mixing in commutativity issues) by mathematical induction is well beyond what is appropriate for this age group, or for that matter, most anyone aside from college math majors -- see [this 12 September 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/MQRGtT7kVKE/m/TIIQ7C7O7vQJ) for what's involved. However, for moderately strong high school students, one could probably prove pairwise equivalence of some of the 5 associative possibilities for 4 numbers.

Comment: Cuisenaire Rods: https://www.teaching.com.au/catalogue/mta/mta-cuisenaire-rods

Comment: @AdamRubinson *"This may work for some weak students. But many weak students don't know how to work out the area of a rectangle, so considerable time would have to be spent working on this in order for your method to be plausible."* Then teach them how to work out the area of a rectangle or the volume of a rectangular cuboid! Take little actual cubes with you, and arrange them in a rectangle. Count the cubes along the width and length, and count the total number of cubes. If the numbers you multiply are too big to count all cubes, bring weighing scales (make sure the cubes have uniform weight)

Answer (score 8):

I think having a student play with examples is a great approach, and that seems the easiest route to having them see *that* this is true.

If seeing multiple permutations of factors all giving the same result isn't convincing, or if they want a different way to conceptualize the situation, maybe draw a model of a product like $2\times5\times3$ and show that pieces can be rearranged. You'd have to choose in advance how to interpret an expression like $a\times b\times c$, say where there are $c$ objects, each containing $a\times b$ smaller units.
[image]

Here, each of three given rectangles has $2\times 5$ little squares in it. Put them together, shade in different parts (in this case columns), reform the columns into rectangles, and then interpret this new picture as a new product (using the original factors, just reordered).

I'm not totally sure how a conversation like this would go with a student, whether they would be satisfied with it. I guess it would all come down to how student and instructor decide to interpret multiplication. [E.g. If $a$ means "number of rows in each rectangle", $b$ means "number of columns in each rectangle" and $c$ means "number of rectangles", then you could just rotate each rectangle to start with to get other expressions like $5\times 2 \times 3$.]

[Edit: I can see that my color choice probably wasn't great, since it looks like red changed size.]

Comment: 2×5×3 are arranged vertically, while 2×3×5 are arranged horizontally. They look different. In fact, they look more like 15×2 :)

Comment: @RustyCore I guess you'll just have to transpose that last row of shapes into a column.

Comment: For a student who cannot represent multiplication of two numbers as an area, that transposition my be the bridge they would not know how to cross. Just sayin'. And you are right with color change. Maybe there should be a "purgatory" stage where all colors change to gray.

Comment: @RustyCore "For a student who cannot represent multiplication of two numbers as an area..." This example presupposes that they can, and that both teacher and student agree where the factors show up in the picture.

Answer (score 5):

Some great answers were provided here, but I wanted to add something which I think is essential: *to emphasize to the student that it is a very good thing to question this!* Why am I saying that? Because indeed, for many operations in algebra the [associative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) does not hold! For example, when talking about division: $8/(4/2) \neq (8/4)/2$. So in fact I would go so far as to say, that a student who questions this may have a latent / undeveloped talent for Math! Because clearly here is an example of a single operation, namely division, where the associative property does not hold. So I would definitely compliment the student for not taking this for granted, and go on to explain that multiplication is one of the *special* operations where it holds that $a\times(b \times c) = (a\times b)\times c$ and therefore we can drop the parentheses without ambiguity.

A similar example can also explain the [commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of multiplication: $2 \times 4 = 4 \times 2$ but $2 / 4 \neq 4 / 2$. Actually I realize that this is actually more relevant to the examples given in the question, and in fact it is important to notice the *implication* of having these two properties *together* for a single operation such as multiplication.
It can actually be a fun exercise for a student to prove that given:

1. $(a \times b) \times c = a \times (b \times c)$
2. $a \times b = b \times a$

then also: $ a \times b \times c = c \times b \times a $ .

Note that given only 1. *or* 2., this doesn't hold! This is also a source of (justified) confusion: a lot of students implicitly think that commutativity (swapping rule) implies associativity, but those are totally independent properties.

Another thing which occasionally helps here is to ask the student the simplest possible question: "*What is bothering you about this rule?*". I think I've already established, there *is* something to be bothered about here. But the student, not always having the faculty with words to *explain* what is bothering him, just feels "silly" and "inadequate" to deal with the problem. In other words, he feels that it is already *wrong* to be *bothered* about something so "simple", which is absolutely bananas! The opposite is true.

Comment: This answer is no less great than the others.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is "and".

1. List the principle.  But NOT in a symbolic (ab) manner.  Just "you can change the order when multiplying."  [Realize you will need to repeat it, several times.  They are not programmable machines.  But just keep doing so.]

-and-

2. Each time they miss it, have them do a few simpler examples.  2 x 3 x 4.  2 x 5 x 10. (in a couple orders)  [After a while, they will get sick of it.  And decide to remember the principle.]

---

So, net net, I think your instincts are correct in recognizing that weaker students won't learn axiomatically).  They are different than you. But in degree...we all share traits of ability and disability in intellect.  Unless you're Von Neumann, you need drill, to engrain math tricks.  He of course was a Martian.  But human brains are more like Harry Potter's hand.  Need Umbridge's pen to furrow some lines into it/them.

P.s.  I think the "like a rectangular prism volume" is low likely to succeed.  Wrong pedagogic insight.  It's MUCH more likely that repeated statements and practice will make things click than some magic explanation (in this case a hard one).  That doesn't mean, you can't have them, can't try them.  After all the "and" principle applies.  And you should try lots of things.  But.  I would not think "key explanation" (like a lock and key) is the way to overcome these hurdles.  It's more likely that familiarization is what is needed.  And yes, more than you would need.  More than what a high IQ student would need.

P.s.s.  I don't think of rectangles with multiplication as Xander mentions.  I'm not a Ph.D. mathematician. But a decent ex-STEM student.  And I think of  multiplication as extension of the times table (via long multiplcation).  I.e. algebraically. If I really scratch my head and think of the times table itself, I probably think of repeated addition.  This is NOT to say that it's the preferred way.  Just that rectangles are not something everyone thinks of.  I'm always pleasantly surprised by geometric drawings for Pythagoras or the like...since I don't think as geometrically.  Again, not even saying this is good. Just saying the impulse to think that everyone thinks in one manner (the way one does) is a mistake.  I mean...heck with exponentiation do you think first of repeated multiplication or think first of "more dimensions in Flatland"!?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers here have been geometric. Here is an answer for three or more factors that is algebraic. It requires the student to know that multiplication is associative (more understandable to them, "we can put parentheses anywhere because of order of operations", maybe needs additional justification), the commutative law for two numbers (justified well by the rectangles in the other answers) and that two equal expressions can be substituted for one another.

Sample explanation:

Start with $38 \times 27 \times 14$. We are not going to calculate this, but if we were, we would need to multiply two of the numbers together first, and then multiply that result times the third number. What that means in symbols is that we might actually calculate $ (38 \times 27) \times 14$. Because multiplication is associative, we could also do $ 38 \times (27 \times 14) $.

To summarize, $38 \times 27 \times 14 = (38 \times 27) \times 14 = 38 \times (27 \times 14)$. Let's say we went with $(38 \times 27) \times 14$, and just take a look at $(38 \times 27)$ on its own. Because of our commutative law, we know that $(38 \times 27) = (27 \times 38)$, and since we can substitute equal expressions into a third expression, our original is now $38 \times 27 \times 14 = (38 \times 27) \times 14 = (27 \times 38) \times 14$. We can then move the brackets again (associativity) and switch 38 and 14 to get the final answer.

The bottom line is that by doing this trick, we can see that when we have a bunch of numbers multiplied together, we can switch them around in any order.

Comment: As an aside commenting on whether this answer truly meets the other, overall need of helping the student achieve proficiency in addition to understanding, I am not sure the difference between a student who can successfully recognize the applicability of the commutative law and apply it and one who cannot is that the former has a very clear justification of *why* this can be done for an arbitrary number of factors.

Answer (score 2):

Many college students have a 2nd issue with a problem like this. If they see 2(3 · 4), they sometimes want to distribute, and write 2·3 · 2·4. Yikes. This one requires seeing the difference between distributive property and a · b · c. We work on that.

First, we go back to areas and volumes. My answer is therefore much like Jasper's. Yes, considerable time must be spent on these basics for further mathematical steps to have any meaning for them.

I ask: What is the area of a rectangle? Someone tells me. Most of them nod.
I ask: Why? They look at me like I'm nuts. They think of it as a "formula", and they think of those as givens.

So I have them look at the ceiling tiles (because the floor tiles are 1 foot by 1 foot and don't teach area). We estimate those to be 2 feet by 4 feet. So that's 2 rows of 4 tiles each. We could count, or we could ... multiply, yes.

Once we've done one more problem like that on the board, and they are *seeing* that the multiplication is how many rows times how much in a row, then we go to volume. I use my hands to "create" (mime) a cardboard box on top of my desk. It's 4 feet across, 3 feet front to back, and 2 feet high. We imagine small 1 cubic foot boxes being packed inside. There are 3 rows of 4 on the bottom layer, and then there's a top layer. How many? 12 and 12 is 24 of the cubic foot boxes. Could we count vertical layers from front to back? Sure. The front 'layer' is 4 by 2, and then they go 3 back. 8 times 3 is also 24. And we could go left to right. 3 by 2 is 6, 4 times that is still 24 cubic feet. Of course.

I also reteach distributive property, using visuals. My goal is always to help them to see *why*.

Answer (score 1):

Exercise: Following are several products of the same 3 numbers, but in different orders. Calculate these products using a calculator.

14 x 27 x 38

14 x 38 x 27

27 x 14 x 38

27 x 38 x 14

38 x 14 x 27

38 x 27 x 14

What do you notice? Pick three other numbers to test your conjecture.

Does this work with addition?

Does it work with subtraction?

Answer (score 1):

**Introduce them some of euclid's axioms.** For example:

> Things that are equal to the same thing are also equal to one another
> .

> If equals are added to equals, then the wholes are equal (Addition property of equality).

> If equals are divided from equals, then the results are equal (division property of equality).

Then, show them with examples how these axioms can be used to prove the desire things ( You can give them a chance prior to this if you wish so). It would not result into any unfairness if they accept it as common sense because these are accepted axioms and not informal shortcuts.

Comment: Why do you prefer an axiomatic approach for a student who is weak at mathematics?

Comment: @DavidSteinberg  Because axioms which I mentioned are not uncommon outside math world and hence would be good for newbies to accept as common sense.

Answer (score 0):

When Xander wrote in his comment to his answer, "If these students cannot work out the area of a rectangle, what is their mental model of multiplication?", I think a more relevant comment is, "If these students cannot work out the area of a rectangle, then they shouldn't yet be trying to learn that $ab = ba,$ let alone $abc = cab.$" I should build multiplication up with geometry at the same level of multiplication that we are working on, with geometry as a helpful tool assisting in the understanding of multiplication, in a similar manner one would use money problems to assist in the teaching of addition. And I shouldn't try to cover all of "numbers" (standard form, HCF/LCM, etc) before moving onto geometry later on; with strong students this might be possible, as we can cover  ground more quickly, but with weak students - which is what we are talking about here - it isn't an effective teaching strategy, I guess.

Comment: The intention of my question was not to suggest that areas of rectangles are necessarily the "correct" primitive notion.  Rather, the actual question as the important part:  What mental model do the students have for multiplication?  The way that you approach the various properties of multiplication depends on what they understand multiplication to mean in the first place.  Geometry is only one possible approach.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Please can you give me an example of what you're talking about and how it relates to the question.

Comment: I did give an example:  some students are taught that multiplication is about finding the area of rectangles.  If you have five rows of coins, each of which contains seven coins, then the total number of coins is the area of that rectangle, i.e. 35 coins.  **If** this is the mental model that students have, **then** commutativity comes about by swapping length and width.  But if your students are building their idea of multiplication on a different mental model, then another instructional strategy is likely needed.

Comment: But I have already addressed everything in your comment. Firstly,  *some* students I am referring to might have the notion of area you suggest. *Others* may have no concept of area, but their concept of multiplication is that $5$ *groups* of $7$ coins gives you $35$ coins., but these groups are not arranged into rows and columns in their mental model. And you have said before that if this is the case, then the next thing to teach them is that the groups can be arranged into rows and columns, so this will update their mental model, and I agree with this.

Comment: Secondly, you say "commutativity comes about...", but in order to show that $abc = cab, $ that is for $n=3,$ and $abcd = dacb$, that is $n=4,$  we actually need commutativity *and* associativity, right? But like I have said before, axiomatic approach is not appropriate for these students.

Comment: (1) Again, my comment was *only* meant to point out that good pedagogy builds on what students already know. *Start* with what they know, and try to build from there.  Computing area is an *example*, which presupposes that students already know how multiplication and area relate to each other.  (2) You don't *need* associativity in order to convince students that multiplication is commutative.  Extending the area example, in three dimensions, you can rotate a rectangular prism in any way, permuting the length, width, and height. To make it rigorous, sure, associativity. But that isn't the goal

Comment: "You don't need associativity in order to convince students that multiplication is commutative. " But we're not *just* trying to convince students that multiplication is commutative...

Comment: Let me clarify: your question seems to be "How do I convince weak students that "abc = cab = bca = acb = cba = bac?  That is, how do I convince students that multiplication can be done in any order?"  From an axiomatic point of view, this requires both commutativity ($ab = ba$) and associativity ($a(bc) = (ab)c$).  But students who are struggling to understand the basic mechanics of multiplication aren't helped by these abstract notions.  It is sufficient to say "you can do the multiplication in any order you like", and find some way to justify this, e.g. by permuting the sides of a solid.

Comment: I get that, and I appreciate your time in replying to me. You said in your first reply, "Geometry is only one possible approach." What other approach is there? I mean, I would  consider the only approach that students might have that is *not* geometric to be the "grouping of coins" one I mentioned in an earlier comment. But then my point of this answer was that, if they *do not* have a geometric notion of area, then this knowledge gap should be filled and only then should they learn $ab=ba$ geometrically because that *is* the best mental model - it is better than the groups of coins one, no?

Comment: I have five piles of coins, each of which contains seven coins.  I am going to make new piles as follows:  take one coin from each of my original piles, and put them in a new pile.  Then take a second coin from each of the original piles, and put them into a second new pile.  Keep doing this.  I will end up with piles of five coins (since my new piles contain one coin from each of the original plies), and there will be a total of seven piles (since each of my original piles had seven coins).  This gives you commutativity.

Comment: To expand this to more factors, try thinking about putting coins into bags:  put $a$ coins into each of $b$ little bags, then put these $b$ little bags into a big bag.  Do this $c$ times.  This gives you $abc$.  Now rearrange.

Comment: Well, yes, that's an extension of my "grouping of coins" example, and I think you word it well. It might work well with students who are good at maths in general but *don't like* or are poor at geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Start with simpler examples. So, start with explaining why $\ 1 \times 2 = 2 \times 1$, then $\ 2 \times 3 = 3 \times 2$, etc.

Next, proceed to $\ 1 \times 2 \times 3 = 2 \times 3 \times 1$, $\ 1 \times 2 \times 4 = 2 \times 4 \times 1$, etc.

Etc.

The examples you give are ridiculously complex and intimidating for a student who doesn't yet understand (or "believe") that multiplication is commutative. But once she gets the above simple examples and understands the concept, she should be able to easily extend it to your examples.

---

P.S. You repeatedly use the word *weak* to describe your students and even mention that "when I was that age, I found both of those steps "obvious"". Perhaps your student aren't as smart as you.

But if your goal is to be an effective teacher, perhaps it's better to abandon such beliefs and negative thoughts (satisfying as they may be for your ego):

- Concede that you are not a good teacher and seek to improve (rather than blame your students for their failure to learn).
- Believe it or not, your students probably know that you think they're stupid. This is very demoralizing and intimidating for them and makes it that much harder for them to learn (especially from you).

Comment: You say to explain this and that, but you don't say *how* to explain it. The original poster was asking for ideas about how to explain things. Also, in my understanding, the complicated examples were examples of calculations where it might come in handy to apply commutativity in solving the kinds of problems students in the 12-16 age group are typically asked to do. I don't think they were intended as examples of how the poster would go about teaching commutativity (which is what the poster wanted to learn how to do).

Comment: @WillOrrick: My answer is meant to complement the other answers already given here. I merely wanted to make one very important point, which is that the teacher should start with simplest possible examples, then work her way up. I did not want this important point to be obscured by other points.

Comment: First of all, this isn't about multiplication being commutative. It's about multiplication being commutative *and* associative. Am I wrong about this? Either many people have made this mistake in answering my question, or I am wrong about this. For example, you cannot show that $(ab)c = a(bc)$ without the associativity axiom for multiplication, since this *is* the associativity axiom for multiplication which wouldn't exist if it was redundant, right? That all said, axiom stuff is not applicable to the original question as I have stated many times before.

Comment: Secondly, you say, "The examples you give are ridiculously complex and intimidating for a student who doesn't yet understand (or "believe") that multiplication is commutative. But once she gets the above simple examples and understands the concept, she should be able to easily extend it to your examples". I disagree with literally all of your opinions here. They are just about the simplest examples I can think of. Can you think of simpler ones that aren't trivial? Secondly, just because they believe two or three numbers in a product can be rearranged without changing the result, does not...

Comment: ... mean it is obvious it can be done for four or more numbers. Thirdly, you say, "Concede that you are not a good teacher and seek to improve (rather than blame your students for their failure to learn)." I don't think I'm a bad teacher, but I do seek to improve. Also, I don't *blame them* for their failure to learn. [What makes you think this??] I *am* trying to help them. Maybe I should stop calling them "weak students", but rather, "students who haven't learned the fundamentals sufficiently well". Fair enough, I guess.

Comment: "Believe it or not, your students probably know that you think they're stupid. This is very demoralizing and intimidating for them and makes it that much harder for them to learn (especially from you)." I don't think they are "stupid", but obviously *I do know maths better than them*. I guess I could make it my responsibility to ensure they don't feel inferior? And perhaps the result I am trying to show them with this question is not even obvious: it just seems to me to be obvious. But for example, maybe there are similar (but subtly different) abstract settings where the result is false.

Comment: "Concede that you are not a good teacher". How did you determine that I'm not a good teacher? Your "answer" is riddled with unjustified assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can teach/remind him to simplify $(38×27×14)/(27×14×38)$. If he knows the same number can be eliminated from both sides regardless of the position to simplify a fraction, he'll get 1, meaning they're equal.